# IDA PRO: How to set conditional breakpoint on a register value?

Tags: ida

I want to set a breakpoint when the register EAX = 00000001

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want a breakpoint to fire every time `eax` is `1`, no matter what address? That's not possible with any debugger. If you mean you want to set a breakpoint **at a particular address** that only fires when `eax` is `1`, that's doable.

1. Set a breakpoint on some instruction with `F2`.
2. Right-click on the instruction and choose `Edit breakpoint...`.
3. Write `EAX == 1` in the `Condition` field on the dialog box.

The `Edit breakpoint` dialog is described in great detail in the IDA manual. Search for "Edit breakpoint"; there are several pages describing it.

Comment: This could be possible with Unicorn Engine, though (or Qiling). However, I'll admit that this sort of goes beyond the original question with IDA as its scope.

Comment: As I mentioned to the poster in a comment on another one of his questions (https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26266/ida-pro-how-to-set-conditional-breakpoint-on-a-eax-register-value/26267), this type of request is stepping outside of what the x86 debug interface offers naturally, and requires something like emulation or DBI.