# IDA PRO: How to set conditional breakpoint on a EAX register value?

Tags: ida

I want a breakpoint when the EAX record == 1. here's an IDC script that does this, but it is very slow. does anyone have a faster script or plugin that does this?

```
#include <idc.idc>

static main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        StepInto();
         
        if (GetDebuggerEvent(WFNE_SUSP, -1) == STEP)
        {
            if (GetRegValue("EAX") == 0) 
            {
                msg("EAX:%08Xh\n", eax);
                break;
            }
        }        
    }
    PauseProcess();
}
```

Comment: i remember using tracing feature in ida free 5 with a non address dependent break on register condition like eax==0xdeadbeef not sure if thats faster than your idc  ollydbg trace protocol used to be faster than ida trace

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is not compatible with the way debugging works on x86. It has limited debugging facilities; you can set hardware breakpoints on read or write access to up to four memory locations, and you can set software or hardware breakpoints when executing particular address. There's nothing in the x86 debug interface that allows you to tell the processor to stop executing when a register obtains a particular value. What you've done with single-stepping is the closest you'll get with the x86 debug interface. If you want something with better performance, look into writing a plugin for a dynamic binary instrumentation (DBI) framework such as Intel PIN or DynamoRIO.

Comment: does the trace option use any heuristics and trace faster than a dump idc single stepper ?